# Why boolean value is singleton in nature [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript

```
var bool1 = false
var bool2 = false

bool1 === bool2
```

The last statement returns true, which means bool1 & bool2 points to same object instance, I want to understand why is that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`boolean` is a [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) data type, not an object. The [strict comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), performs first a check if the type is the same and then the value.

> Two Boolean operands are strictly equal if both are `true` or both are `false`.

If you take the an object instance of [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean),

> The `Boolean` object is an object wrapper for a boolean value.

you get `false` with strict equality.

```js
var bool1 = new Boolean(false),
    bool2 = new Boolean(false);

console.log(bool1 === bool2);
```

Answer (score 0):

triple equal ( === ) matches value and type. as both are primitive type it returns true.

And if bool1 & bool2 same instance object then changing one value will change another but it will definitely not change other value when you change either bool1 or bool.